# How do I force a video to refresh the active frame when changing time?

Tags: javascript, html, video

When working with the HTML5 video player, I noticed weird behaviour:

When taking the little handle on the timeline and dragging it around (changing the currentTime variable basically), the frame displayed does not update accordingly. Only when I let go of the handle, or move it rather slowly, the currently displayed frame will update from time to time.

How can I force the video player to update the frame quicker, so that I can skip around in the video fluently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the frame you dragged the timeline to, the video player would have to be able to go to the point you are at at that moment, request and download the relevant part of the video file, decode it and then display it.

In practice this is not practical for most players, certainly end user ones.

The workaround that you will see with many video services, is that a set of thumbnails for the video is created, usually when the video us being transcoded in preparation for being streamed.

This is a much smaller file and the individual thumbnails are standalone - i.e. they don't rely on any of the previous or following frames to decode and display them, meaning they can be accessed and fetched much more quickly.

This set of thumbnails may have a frame at every 5 seconds point in the video, for example, and they can be much more readily accessed and displayed when the user scans along the thumb line.

Comment: That sounds really good, however the video I am currently working with is only 15 seconds long and should easily be buffered by the browser. Isn't this the case?

Comment: It will depend on the player but I suspect they simply don't expect to provide this functionality, and they would not provide functionality specially for a video that is that short, so they would not be optimised to do this quickly.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you have any reference on how to implement the thumbnail functionality with JavaScript?

Comment: I'm not aware of an open example. Both Dash and Shaka player are looking at it at the moment: https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/DASH-IF-IOP/tree/master/thumbnails. ,  https://github.com/google/shaka-player/issues/559

Comment: Thanks for your help!